# How to convert a Data Frame to list in R using one column as names of the list?

Tags: r

I have smth like this,

```
> ex <- data.frame(a = 1:20, b = 20:1, c = c(letters[1:10],letters[1:10]))
> head(ex, n = 3)
    a  b c
  1 1 20 a
  2 2 19 b
  3 3 18 c
```

and I want to convert it in smth like this

```
> head(df2list2(df = ex,namecol = "c"), n = 2)
$a
    a  b
1   1 20
11 11 10

$b
    a  b
2   2 19
12 12  9
```

The ugly bunch of code I have used in this function is the following:

```
df2list2 <- function(df,namecol){
 nc = which(colnames(df)==namecol)
 nl = list()
 names = unique(df[,nc])
 for (i in names){
   tmp = df[df[,nc] == i,]
   nl[[i]] = tmp[,-nc]
 }
 return(nl)
}
```

It is dreadfully slow and not very elegant, I may try to do smth more efficient but I just wanted to know if there is an easy workaround to do this transformation.

Comment: `split` is the function you are looking for.

Comment: great to know! It looks equally slow, though. Maybe I should rethink my data type choice.